# Joining Ubuntu to Azure Active Directory - Insufficient permissions to modify computer account

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id

Why am I being told I have insufficient permission despite my user being a member of AAD DC Administrators in Azure - Which I believe is the requirement for updating computer accounts

Followed the official instructions here:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-join-ubuntu-linux-vm

Eventually I worked out that I needed to add my users to that group

When I finally run
sudo realm join --verbose CONTOSO100.COM -U 'bob@CONTOSO100.COM' --install=/

```
Calculated computer account: CN=CONTOSO-UBUNTU,OU=AADDC Computers,DC= 
contoso100,DC=com
! Insufficient permissions to modify computer account: CN=CONTOSO- 
UBUNTU,OU=AADDC Computers,DC= contoso100,DC=com: 000020E7: AtrErr: 
DSID-031530D8, #1:
0: 000020E7: DSID-031530D8, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, 
Att 90008 (userAccountControl):len 4
adcli: joining domain contoso100.com failed: Insufficient permissions 
to modify computer account: CN=CONTOSO-UBUNTU,OU=AADDC Computers,DC= 
contoso100,DC=com: 000020E7: AtrErr: DSID-031530D8, #1:
0: 000020E7: DSID-031530D8, problem 1005 (CONSTRAINT_ATT_TYPE), data 0, 
Att 90008 (userAccountControl):len 4

! Insufficient permissions to join the domain
realm: Couldn't join realm: Insufficient permissions to join the domain
```

Strange things that happened:

When running kinit for a new user it asks for my password
But always returns
`kinit: Preauthentication failed while getting initial credentials`

If I enter a blank password it says password expired and allows me to enter a new one. After this I can authenticate with the new password but this password is now not the same password I used to log into azure.
Which says to me I can't even be sure its the same linked user. But it is definitely checking AD for my user accounts because it will tell me it can't find the account if I enter one that doesn't exist